# Can my find() query include multiple of the same field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose, I'm looking to filter through a collection in my database by using a bunch of different fields, sometimes repeating the same field in the query.

**For example:**

I have fields called "color", "size", and "name" in my 'stamps' collection.

Sometimes I want to get all of the red stamps:

```
await Stamp.find({color: 'red'}).exec();
```

Sometimes I want to get all stamps that are red *and* blue:

```
await Stamp.find({color: 'red', color: 'blue'}).exec();
```

My question is: If the above query is acceptable, would a query like the following be acceptable as well? Or is there a better way of doing things? (looking for best practices)

```
await Stamp.find({color: 'red', color: 'blue', size: 'small', size: 'large'}).exec();
```

Comment: Look like `$in` is what you need.

Comment: `$or` can work also, if you have few values, but `$in` is more general